# How to get the version comments using webservice?

Tags: 2013, development

IN a Nintex workflow(not really relevant), I need to get the User comments for a page, (the last version comments), however Nintex does not show comments in the item properties.

For this I need to use List.asmx webservice,  Does anyone knows how can I get version comments, using this webservice?

Or maybe is a different webservice, I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Versions.GetVersions Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/versions.versions.getversions.aspx) of [Versions Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/versions.versions%28v=office.12%29.aspx) could be used for retrieving information about the versions (including comments) of the specified pages.

```
public XmlNode GetVersions (
    string fileName
)
```

where `filename` is site-relative URL of the page

### Example

The following request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVersions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <fileName>/news/Pages/Latest-News.aspx</fileName>
    </GetVersions>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

will return the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVersionsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <GetVersionsResult>
        <results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
          <list id="{BE43CCF2-5CA7-4957-BF81-7CDC86744D9B}" />
          <versioning enabled="1" />
          <settings url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/news/_layouts/15/LstSetng.aspx?List={BE43CCF2-5CA7-4957-BF81-7CDC86744D9B}" />
          <result version="@2.0" url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/news/Pages/Latest-News.aspx" created="3/28/2014 4:00 AM" createdRaw="2014-03-28T11:00:58Z" createdBy="i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" createdByName="User Name" size="2922" comments="Latest comment from me" />
          <result version="1.0" url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/news/_vti_history/512/Pages/Latest-News.aspx" created="3/7/2014 5:54 AM" createdRaw="2014-03-07T13:54:26Z" createdBy="i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" createdByName="User Name" size="2686" comments="" />
        </results>
      </GetVersionsResult>
    </GetVersionsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then `comment` attribute values could be extracted from `result` elements